# How to prove Kepler's 3rd law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, history

How to prove [Kepler's 3rd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion)? How did Kepler proved it? Is it possible to prove the third law without applying Newton's universal law of gravitation?

Comment: Kepler demonstrated those laws by using experimental data.  He did not prove (i.e. derive) them theoretically.

Comment: Those laws hold for a $-k/r$ potential. If you avoid Newton's UGL, then how do planets move?

Answer (score 0):

We can derive the third law from the first two... sort of. The $\theta = 0$ case of the orbit's polar formula gives $a(1-e)=\dfrac{L^2}{GMm^2(1+e)}$, which I'll rearrange as $a^2(1-e^2)=\dfrac{L^2}{GMm^2}$. Unfortunately, the $G$ for gravity can only be obtained with a little ingredient from Newton, viz. the Binet equation $u+\dfrac{d^2 u}{d\theta^2}=\dfrac{GMm^2}{L^2}$. Next, Kepler's second law can be stated in terms of angular momentum, viz. $P=\dfrac{2m\pi ab}{L}$, where $P$ is the period and $\pi ab$ is the elliptical area the orbit encloses. Using $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$ gives $$P^2=\frac{4\pi^2 m^2 a^2 b^2}{L^2}=\frac{4\pi^2 m^2 a^4 (1-e^2)}{L^2}=\frac{4\pi^2 a^3}{GM}.$$If we insist on a no-Newton analysis, all we can say is $$a(1-e^2)\propto L^2,\,P^2\propto\frac{a^4(1-e^2)}{L^2},\,P^2\propto a^3.$$And even then, we need an understanding of angular momentum not inherent in Kepler's original formulation of the laws.

Comment: How you derived the first equation can you derived  it please? I think you've applied Newton's law of gravitation to derive it .

Comment: @KaustavGuhaRoy I have and I haven't. Kepler's first law says $r=\dfrac{\ell}{1+e\cos\theta}$, and Newtonian gravity gives you a formula for the semi-latus rectum $\ell$.